# Add a GeckoFX WPF browser to a grid's children

Tags: c#, wpf, geckofx

The plan is to render some exported 3D `Marmoset viewer` scene using `geckofx` that was downloaded as a nu-get package in VS. I coded it like this:

```
var targetGrid = (parent as BrowseWares).ViewerGrid;

var viewer = new GeckoWebBrowser();
viewer.LoadHtml("dumbbell.html",
       "C:\\Users\\agoston\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\HP_hf_shop\\HP_hf_shop\\HTML\\dumbbell.html");
targetGrid.Children.Add(viewer);
```

But the problem is that `GeckWebBrowser` is not a `UIElement`. How to correctly use the URL and how to put it inside of that grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably GeckoWebBrowser is a Windows Form component. Host it in a WindowsFormsHost.

Something like:

```
WindowsFormsHost whost = new WindowsFormsHost(); 
GeckoWebBrowser browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
whost.Child = browser; 
targetGrid.Children.Add(whost);
```